# Microsoft Teams ‘chats: getAllMessages’ API on 'v1.0'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

As per the documentation ‘chats: getAllMessages’ (GET /users/{id | user-principal-name}/chats/getAllMessages) of MSTeams Export API is available only as a beta endpoint [1] [2]. But as this is a limitation for us, I checked the ‘chats: getAllMessages’ API on ‘v1.0’ endpoint by changing the endpoint URL and It worked.

I checked ‘getAllMessages’ for a couple of different users on v1.0 and beta endpoints traversing through all result pages. For both users, results are the almost same between 'v1.0' and 'beta' (except for these; Beta has a field 'eventDetail', but the value is null for all & Attachment ids are different) which should be fine for us.

So as v1.0 seems to be fine, I would like to get confirmation on whether 'chats: getAllMessages' is production-ready on v1.0 endpoint.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/export-teams-content

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chats-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0):

This API endpoint is available in v1.0 also.
You can check if the particular API is supported in v1.0 or not, you can use the version selector like below:
[image]